# Make tkinter treeview remember uploaded Excel file when you click on a back to menu button

Tags: python, tkinter, return

I want to code a back to menu button in tkinter. So in my current code that I make, I make the menu_widget_frame to store a combo box. The values is 'SVC', 'McDonalds', and 'Overall SOH data. For each selection of the combo box, I created a function. For the SVC data, the user has to input data by browsing and uploading Excel file to treeview. My svc data is more or less like this:

```
def SVC_data():
global overall_data_svc_table, Excel_file_button_svc, Excel_file_label_svc, svc_predict_stock_level_button, overall_data_svc_table, go_back_to_menu_button_svc, save_file_button_svc
side_bar_svc_data = ttk.Frame(tab2)
side_bar_svc_data.pack(side='left')

svc_data_treeview_frame = ttk.Frame(tab2)
svc_data_treeview_frame.pack(side='right')

columns_data_svc = ('Dates', 'Frozen Quantity', 'Chiller Quantity', 'Dry Quantity')
overall_data_svc_table = ttk.Treeview(svc_data_treeview_frame, show="headings", columns=columns_data_svc)
overall_data_svc_table.pack(anchor='e')

overall_data_svc_table.column(0, width=130)
overall_data_svc_table.column(1, width=130)
overall_data_svc_table.column(2, width=130)
overall_data_svc_table.column(3, width=130)

overall_data_svc_table.heading(0, text="Dates")
overall_data_svc_table.heading(1, text="Frozen Quantity")
overall_data_svc_table.heading(2, text="Chiller Quantity")
overall_data_svc_table.heading(3, text="Dry Quantity")

def upload_excel_file_():
    global file_svc_data
    file_svc_data = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel file", '.xlsx')])

    #The global keyword is used to make the df object available to all functions and scopes within the current module or file.
    global df_svc_data

    #file name has to be in .xlsx
    #example df = pd.readexcel('C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\products.xlsx')
  
    df_svc_data = pd.read_excel(file_svc_data)
    df_svc_data['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df_svc_data['Dates']).dt.strftime('%d-%B-%Y')
    for iid, dates in zip(overall_data_svc_table.get_children(), df_svc_data['Dates']):
        overall_data_svc_table.set(iid, 'Dates', dates)

    #>>>>create a table to show the file forecast inbound<<<<
    list_values = list(df_svc_data.values)
    for value_tuple in list_values[1:]:
        overall_data_svc_table.insert("", 'end', values=value_tuple)
    return None

#create a button & a label to upload Excel file button 
Excel_file_label_svc = ttk.Label(side_bar_svc_data, text='Browse and Upload Excel File')
Excel_file_label_svc.pack(anchor='w')
Excel_file_button_svc = ttk.Button(side_bar_svc_data, text='Display Excel File', command=upload_excel_file_)
Excel_file_button_svc.pack(anchor='w', padx=0, pady=5, expand=1, fill='both')

def predict_stock_level_svc_button_clicked():
    get_latest_dates_value = str(df_svc_data['Dates'].tail(1).values[0])
    latest_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(get_latest_dates_value, "%d-%B-%Y")

    global get_latest_chiller_value_svc, get_latest_dry_value_svc, get_latest_frozen_value_svc

    get_latest_frozen_value_svc = pd.to_numeric(df_svc_data['Frozen Quantity'].tail(1).values[0], downcast='float')
    get_latest_dry_value_svc = pd.to_numeric(df_svc_data['Dry Quantity'].tail(1).values[0], downcast='float')
    get_latest_chiller_value_svc = pd.to_numeric(df_svc_data['Chiller Quantity'].tail(1).values[0], downcast='float')

    for delta in range(1, 367):
        future_dates_svc = latest_date + datetime.timedelta(days=delta)
        future_dates_svc_formatted = future_dates_svc.strftime('%d-%B-%Y')
        total_latest_data = future_dates_svc_formatted, get_latest_frozen_value_svc, get_latest_dry_value_svc, get_latest_chiller_value_svc
        overall_data_svc_table.insert("", 'end', values=total_latest_data)

    return None

#create a svc predict button to calculate stock level
svc_predict_stock_level_button = ttk.Button(side_bar_svc_data, text='Predict Stock Level', command=predict_stock_level_svc_button_clicked)
svc_predict_stock_level_button.pack(anchor='w', pady=5, expand=1, fill='both')

def save_file_button_selected():
    for child in overall_data_svc_table.get_children():
        row = overall_data_svc_table.item(child)['values']
        df_svc_data.at(row)
        df_svc_data.to_excel(file_svc_data)
    
    return None

def go_back_to_menu_button_selected():
    #call function to hide all widget in the window svc
    side_bar_svc_data.pack_forget()
    svc_data_treeview_frame.pack_forget()
    #go back to the store name menu selection
    menu_widget_frame.pack()

save_file_button_svc = ttk.Button(side_bar_svc_data, text='Save File to Excel', command=save_file_button_selected)
save_file_button_svc.pack(anchor='w', side='left', padx=3, pady=3)

go_back_to_menu_button_svc = ttk.Button(side_bar_svc_data, text='Back to Menu', command=go_back_to_menu_button_selected)
go_back_to_menu_button_svc.pack(anchor='n', side='right', pady=3, padx=1, expand=1)

return None
```

In the SVC data, I created a back to menu button to where it can shows the menu window. I want to know how the back to menu button works if the user wants to go back to see the excel file they have input to treeview. How can you do this? What I have done is so far is trying to make the back to menu_widget_frame.bind all of events. And using this

```
 #Store the uploaded data in a separate variable
global uploaded_svc_data
uploaded_svc_data = df_svc_data

def go_back_to_menu_button_selected():
    # Hide the side bar and treeview frames
    side_bar_svc_data.pack_forget()
    svc_data_treeview_frame.pack_forget()
    
    # Show the menu widget frame
    menu_widget_frame.pack()

    # Check if there is uploaded data and display it in the treeview
    if uploaded_svc_data is not None:
        for iid, dates in zip(overall_data_svc_table.get_children(), uploaded_svc_data['Dates']):
            overall_data_svc_table.set(iid, 'Dates', dates)

        list_values = list(uploaded_svc_data.values)
        for value_tuple in list_values[1:]:
            overall_data_svc_table.insert("", 'end', values=value_tuple)
```

Comment: Your question as currently written is not solvable before a dialog with you or writing a [mre] for you. Please consider [edit]ing your question or asking one that actually meets the community guidelines. see [ask] for starters.

Comment: Why is it not solvable? I thought I make myself clear and I already included my own tries.

Comment: Because we can't tell where and what is accessible without actually refactoring the code snippets into a [mre]. We need to assume what you have done and where your indention are forming a local scope. We need to assume your data structure and how you turn pages. And before you misinterpret my comment to *dump all of your code and data* into your question, that is not what I mean. It means you should have already narrowed down your issue to the minimum and show us exactly where you stuck before asking.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to retain the already loaded data from the Excel file when switching from the menu frame back to *SVC* frame?

Comment: Yes, that's right, acw.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to do this. Since tkInter cannot retain data so that you can switch frame from frame A to frame B, I decided to use a database management system using Google Sheets API to store the data from tkInter treeview and update it automatically using the library 'gspread'. You can also do this by picking your preferable database management system, such as SQL or anything else.